# Nested CSS selector Issue

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors

Hello I have some nested element and I need to select **all the img elements in my page which are inside a infoGif** class element one to change height and border. This is my code:

```html
<div class="column mcb-column mcb-item-3ddazypc9 one-second column_image infoGif">
    <div class="image_frame image_item no_link scale-with-grid no_border">
        <div class="image_wrapper">
            <img class="scale-with-grid" src="https://test.com" height="300">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried with this but didn't work

```css
.infoGif > .image_frame > .image_wrapper > .scale-with-grid { 
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

how should I select it? is there some best practice for selecting such deep elements? Thanks

Comment: You CSS selectors are OK. The problem is with inline height=300; That's why height=100 will always take precedence :) Try removing inline style then try :)

Comment: *How to select it* depends on what exactly you want to select. Just `img` or `.scale-with-grid` would do. What you have _should_ do too, but is more specific. What is the "best" way for your particular situation depends on your particular situation.

Comment: You're asking about best practice, but that's rather subjective. The concrete issue can be caused by anything, for example by having more specific selectors that override this rule.  We can't know without more information.

Comment: Dear @Rita: I will again want to re-iterate on the fact the in your CSS selector chain! Nothing is wrong.... May be your inlne-style is overriding your CSS. Because Inline takes precendence :)

Comment: I cannot remove the inline style cause it's placed by Wordpress... what kind of info can be needed to help me? I basically need to select all instances of img within the .infoGif class

Comment: https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/rNMJvxE

Comment: You will need to add width:100px !important; And your life is sorted :)

Comment: Let me know if it helped or we'll figure another way out :) Don't worry. I have just updated the link... Try this https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/rNMJvxE

Comment: Inspect the element in the browser (right click, Inspect Element), and check the style of the element. The inspector will tell you what styles are applied to the element *and where they come from.*